# Need to stream large QueryRunner result to file, seems to be storing in memory

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc, apache-commons-dbutils

I'm trying to build a Java application that can stream very large result sets of arbitrary SQL SELECT queries into JSONL files, specifically through SQLServer but would like to run with any JDBC `DataSource`. In Python this would be easy to just treat the sql client result as a generator and then call `json.dumps()`. However, in this code it seems like its putting everything in memory before writing out, typically causing heap and garbage collection exceptions. The queries I need this to run for are very large, bringing back up to 10GB of raw data. Execution time is not the primary concern, as long as it works every time.

I've tried calling flush after ever row (which is ridiculous) and that seems to help with small datasets but not with large ones. Can anyone suggest a strategy I can use to pull this off easily?

In my SQL client class I use Apache DbUtils `QueryRunner` and `MapListHandler` to create a list of `Map`s which is the flexibility I need (versus more traditional approaches in Java which require specifying schema and types):

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> query(String queryText) {
    try {
        DbUtils.loadDriver("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver");

        // this function just sets up all the connection properties. Ommitted for clarity
        DataSource ds = this.initDataSource();

        StatementConfiguration sc = new StatementConfiguration.Builder().fetchSize(10000).build();
        QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner(ds, sc);
        MapListHandler handler = new MapListHandler();
        return queryRunner.query(queryText, handler);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

`JsonLOutputWriter` class:

```
JsonLOutputWriter(String filename) {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.serializeNulls();
    this.gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    try {
        this.writer = new PrintWriter(new File(filename), ENCODING);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void writeRow(Map row) {
    this.writer.println(this.gson.toJson(row));
}

void flush() {
    this.writer.flush();
}
```

Main method:

```
JsonLOutputWriter writer = new JsonLOutputWriter(outputFile)
for (Map row : client.query(inputSql)) {
    writer.writeRow(row);
}
writer.flush()
```

Comment: The way you use `QueryRunner` means that first **all** rows are loaded in memory **before** you write them out. Don't do that, process it row by row immediately. You may need to dive down to the JDBC level to do this (and maybe you need to use a smaller fetch size than 10000 if memory is still an issue). Also consider using a bean instead of a `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ok great so I figured I'm doing it wrong. If you have an example way to do it correctly that'd be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this cannot be done with `DbUtils` out of the box. I got rid of `QueryRunner` and `MapListHandler` since the handler creates an `ArrayList`. Instead of being pull based I made it push based, creating a very similar `MyQueryRunner` that takes a `MyRowHandler` and instead of returning a collection just iterates over the `ResultSet` and calls my output function.

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this and return some kind of row buffer, but this is that 80/20 I needed and works for large datasets.

**RowHandler**

```
public class RowHandler {
    private static final RowProcessor ROW_PROCESSOR = new BasicRowProcessor();
    private JsonLOutputWriter writer;

    public RowHandler(JsonLOutputWriter writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    int handle(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        while (rs.next()) {
            writer.writeRow(this.handleRow(rs));
            counter.getAndIncrement();
        }
        return counter.intValue();
    }

    protected Map<String, Object> handleRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        return this.ROW_PROCESSOR.toMap(rs);
    }

}
```

**QueryHandler**

```
class CustomQueryRunner extends AbstractQueryRunner {

    private final RowHandler rh;

    CustomQueryRunner(DataSource ds, StatementConfiguration stmtConfig, RowHandler rh) {
        super(ds, stmtConfig);
        this.rh = rh;
    }

    int query(String sql) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = this.prepareConnection();
        return this.query(conn, true, sql);
    }

    private int query(Connection conn, boolean closeConn, String sql, Object... params)
            throws SQLException {
        if (conn == null) {
            throw new SQLException("Null connection");
        }
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        int count = 0;
        try {
            stmt = this.prepareStatement(conn, sql);
            this.fillStatement(stmt, params);
            rs = this.wrap(stmt.executeQuery());
            count = rh.handle(rs);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            this.rethrow(e, sql, params);
        } finally {
            try {
                close(rs);
            } finally {
                close(stmt);
                if (closeConn) {
                    close(conn);
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```